# Sybase stored procedures / functions / triggers code static analysis tool

Tags: static, sybase, analysis

Please let me know, if anyone knows it, a code static analysis tool for Sybase database (stored procedures, functions, triggers).

Comment: please explain what functionality are you looking for

Comment: Code static analysis tasks (code correctness, efficiency, maintainability, program structure, readability, naming conventions), architecture metrics (problematic sql, complex sql, simple sql, invalid sql, number of sentences, cyclomatic complexity, maintainability index).

Comment: spotlight for sybase check that